# How to replace array item in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, foreach

I have 2 arrays:

1st: $data with old img and link

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Koala.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Jellyfish.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/2"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Hydrangeas.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/3"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Penguins.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/4"
  ]
]
```

2nd: $images new images

```
array:4 [▼
  "slide0" => UploadedFile {#241 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Lighthouse.jpg"
    ....
  }
  "slide1" => UploadedFile {#239 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Penguins.jpg"
   ....
  }
  "slide2" => UploadedFile {#234 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Desert.jpg"
    ....
  }
  "slide3" => UploadedFile {#238 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Tulips.jpg"
   ....
  }
]
```

how to properly do this replace:

```
"img" => "Koala.jpg" to "img" => "Lighthouse.jpg",
"img" => "Jellyfish.jpg" to "img" => "Penguins.jpg",
"img" => "Hydrangeas.jpg" to "img" => "Desert.jpg",
"img" => "Penguins.jpg" to "img" => "Tulips.jpg",
```

?

Im trying to make it this way:

```
foreach($data as $key=>&$item){
            if(isset($images['slide'.$key])){
                $item['img']=$images['slide'.$key]->getClientOriginalName();
            }
        }
```

but last array getting duplicated with pre-last:

```
array(2) { ["img"]=> string(14) "Hydrangeas.jpg" ["link"]=> string(19) "http://site.loc/1" }
array(2) { ["img"]=> string(14) "Lighthouse.jpg" ["link"]=> string(19) "http://site.loc/2" }
array(2) { ["img"]=> string(13) "Jellyfish.jpg" ["link"]=> string(19) "http://site.loc/3" } 
array(2) { ["img"]=> string(13) "Jellyfish.jpg" ["link"]=> string(19) "http://site.loc/3" }
```

Is it possible to prevent duplicate or I should use something else then foreach ?

Also, I noticed when I do this replace with foreach, the last array of multidimensinal array has &

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Hydrangeas.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Koala.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/2"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Jellyfish.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/3"
  ]
  3 => & array:2 [▼
    "img" => "Tulips.jpg"
    "link" => "http://site.loc/4"
  ]
]
```

Maybe thats the reason of duplicate?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem that is probably elsewhere. https://eval.in/752229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Batmannn you can it like below :

```
<?php
    $arr1 = array(
               array(
                "img" => "Koala.jpg",
                "link" => "http://site.loc/1"
               ),
               array(
                "img" => "Jellyfish.jpg",
                "link" => "http://site.loc/2"
               ),
               array(
                "img" => "Hydrangeas.jpg",
                "link" => "http://site.loc/3"
               ),
               array(
                "img" => "Penguins.jpg",
                "link" => "http://site.loc/4"
               )
            );

    $arr2 = array(
                  "slide0" =>
                  array(
                    "test"=> false,
                    "originalName"=> "Lighthouse.jpg"
                  ),
                  "slide1" =>
                  array(
                    "test"=> false,
                    "originalName"=> "Penguins.jpg"
                  ),
                  "slide2" =>
                  array(
                    "test"=> false,
                    "originalName"=> "Desert.jpg"
                  ),
                  "slide3" =>
                  array(
                    "test"=> false,
                    "originalName"=> "Tulips.jpg"
                  )
            );
    $newImageName = array_column($arr2, "originalName");

    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        $arr1[$key]["img"] = $newImageName[$key];
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1); // final result
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you must have two arrays and then you can replace them using array_replace().

Example

```
<?php
$a1=array("abc","def");
$a2=array("xyz","lmn");
print_r(array_replace($a1,$a2));
?>
```

the out put will be

```
Array ( [0] => xyz [1] => lmn )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without any function you can achieve it,

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
   array(
    "img" => "Koala.jpg",
    "link" => "http://site.loc/1"
   ),
   array(
    "img" => "Jellyfish.jpg",
    "link" => "http://site.loc/2"
   ),
   array(
    "img" => "Hydrangeas.jpg",
    "link" => "http://site.loc/3"
   ),
   array(
    "img" => "Penguins.jpg",
    "link" => "http://site.loc/4"
   )
);

  $arr2 = array(
      "slide0" =>
      array(
        "test"=> false,
        "originalName"=> "Lighthouse.jpg"
      ),
      "slide1" =>
      array(
        "test"=> false,
        "originalName"=> "Penguins.jpg"
      ),
      "slide2" =>
      array(
        "test"=> false,
        "originalName"=> "Desert.jpg"
      ),
      "slide3" =>
      array(
        "test"=> false,
        "originalName"=> "Tulips.jpg"
      )
);

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $arr1[$key]["img"] = $arr2['slide'.$key]['originalName'];
}
var_dump($arr1);
```